# How to get the resource id/ xpath for Floating Notification of Android

Tags: android, automation, appium, ui-automation

[image]I want to get the resource-id for the floating notification as shown in the image.

For iOS we have the accessibility-id for floating notifications as -**NotificationShortLookView** . Similarly I am looking for Android OS.

I tried using the xpath like
driver.findElementbyId("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Local Notification']") , but it didn't showed any element. It showed 0 elements as the result. Please suggest

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the resource-id for the Floating Notification by adding another capability to the existing ones called as **enableMultiWindows** and set it **true** in the Appium Desktop application. See the reference Image[image]